# Why doesn't noautohide work in an XUL panel?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm developing a Firefox extension, trying to get a panel to overlay a browser element.  Here is my javascript code:

```
var panel = oldTabBrowser.contentDocument.createElement('panel');
panel.setAttribute('noautohide','true');
var label = oldTabBrowser.contentDocument.createElement('label');
label.setAttribute('value','my text');
panel.appendChild(label);
elem.appendChild(panel);
panel.openPopup(elem, "overlap",0,0);
alert(panel.getAttribute('noautohide'));
```

The `noautohide` attribute is set fine and the panel appears as expected, but on clicking anywhere, the panel disappears.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I have a strong suspicion that `noautohide` attribute doesn't work correctly. At least for `<xul:tooltip>` the result isn't the one I expected. You can however make sure that your panel doesn't close prematurely using [`popuphiding` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/PopupEvents#The_popuphiding_event):

```
var canClose = false;
panel.addEventListener("popuphiding", function(event)
{
  if (!canClose)
  {
    // Too early to close, prevent it
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
panel.openPopup(elem, "overlap",0,0);

...

// Now it is ok to close
canClose = true;
panel.hidePopup();
```

Comment: I dig your suspicion... funny thing is, it works for me in the sidebar, but not in a tab.  Anyway, thanks for the workaround, I'll try it.

Comment: @Yuttadhammo: For me it's rather - first time clicking in the document closes the tooltip. But after opening it again I can click wherever I like and it doesn't close. Seems to be a bug.